# mysql-server-8.0 installation problem on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, software-installation, mysql

I have installed mysql-server-8.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 and the install has not created `/etc/mysql/` ...

I have tried removing and re-installation but it does the same thing every time

```
error : alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have something there? `ls /etc/mysql/`, `dpkg --list | grep mysql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have `/etc/mysql/` files you need to have `mysql-common` package installed. I do not have any mysql server, but the next command shows which package provides what you need.

```
$ dpkg --list | grep mysql
ii  libmysqlclient21:amd64                        8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1             amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-common                                  5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2                    all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

My `/etc/mysql` folder's content:

```
$ ls /etc/mysql/
conf.d  my.cnf  my.cnf.fallback
```

And also, if you want a complete [reinstalling](https://help.cloud66.com/maestro/how-to-guides/databases/shells/uninstall-mysql.html), use purge:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server && sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Comment: Many thanks, I did have mysql-common installed so I purged that as well and started again, all sorted now